# Configure Object-Store for Opscenter

Tags: swift, cassandra, openstack, datastax

Is it possible to use objectstore (swift) provided by openstack via opscenter as a backup-location? In version 5.1.1. backups to Amazon S3 are supported. But how do I configure object-store from another provider?

I only found the link below:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.1/api/docs/backups.html#method-update-a-destination

Answer (score 2):

#### Custom Pre-Post Backup Script

You can use a custom pre-post backup script if you want to back up cassandra to a location that is not on your local file system or on Amazon S3:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.1/opsc/online_help/services/opscSchedulingBackup_t.html

In essence this is a hook for you to run a program before or after the OpsCenter backup. You can use that to push out to Swift.

Here is an example of what a backup script may look like (this one is to back up to S3 which is now obsolete by the S3 functionality in OpsCenter 5.1, but you can use it as an example for your custom Swift script).

https://gist.github.com/phact/7500b6cc9fb6f963c849